# why is my page displaying from the half of the screen and not the full screen?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to pop all the routes before i navigate to my dashboard screen in my flutter app, but the screen is only displaying from the half of the screen,

I have attached a screenshot for reference and i am using the following code in my app.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new BottomNavBar(0)));
```

this is just so annoying i have tried too many ways to navigate to the screen and every time i only see the half of the screen and i am not sure what actually is going wrong.[image]

my only intention is I want to pop all the routes before i navigate to a route named `'/dashboard'` in my app.

Please can someone tell me what might have gone wrong.

Many Thanks
Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the recommended way of doing it, but I've implemented that before like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/dashboard", (Route r) => r == null);
```

Comment: hi @Bram Vanbilsen, thanks for your reply, the problem i thought was i am requesting access to the location before navigating to the dashboard and the screen ends up like this. Now i have changed the same to be after the dashboard screen is launched and its working fine. thanks

Comment: hi @Bram Vanbilsen, this issue occurs if there is any navigation in the app but the app is actually in the background or if the screen is locked. i am using firebase database and I am actually signing out the user when there is a change to the device token. this is obviously `onValue` listener and if the phone is locked and there is a change to token, then even the login screen is shown like the screenshot in the question, i am not sure if i need to file a bug or if this is some kind of rendering issue. I am still getting this issue in the case mentioned in this comment.

Comment: @Mahi have you found a solution? I am also having this issue but in a slightly different case